# WSO2 Ei 6.1 email received as attachment

Tags: wso2

I have a service which send the email from WSo2 server. But i am getting the message content as attachment and not in body of the email.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the message content for the email body using payload factory mediator as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="mailtest"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <test xmlns="">$1</test>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:ax21="http://services.samples/xsd"
                    xmlns:ns="http://services.samples"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="//ns:getQuoteResponse/ns:return/ax21:name"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="Subject" scope="transport" value="Sample Mail"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="text/plain"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="mailto:yourmail@gmail.com"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

If you want to define a message body with the email attachment, use "[transport.mail.bodyWhenAttached](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/MailTo+Transport)" property.